# How to send parameters between viewmodels using viewmodellocator

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, mvvm, viewmodellocator

I am creating a WPF application using MVVMLight. I use ViewModelLocator to create viewmodels. 
My problem is passing parameters between them.

For example we have a situation:

We have a grid with some entities, when one of them is doubleclicked I need to create a new view with details of that entity. How to send the selected item id to ViewModel of the new View?

Comment: Hi are you using any MessagingServices Like that of Galasoft or any Messaging to Communicate from ViewModel to View

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Typically you would use some kind of messaging system, such as Prism's [EventAggregator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff921122%28v=pandp.20%29.aspx) or MVVM Light's [Messenger](http://www.galasoft.ch/mvvm/).

Both systems remind me of a paging system: any part of the application can broadcast messages, and any part of the application and subscribe to listen for messages.

So your DoubleClick command would broadcast a `LoadItemMessage` containing the selected item `Id`, and whatever is responsible for showing the item would subscribe to receive `LoadItemMessages` and would load the item whenever it hears a `LoadItemMessage`.

If you're interested, I have a brief article on my blog about [Communication between Viewmodels with MVVM](http://rachel53461.wordpress.com/2011/06/05/communication-between-viewmodels-with-mvvm/) that gives a high level overview of event systems.

Comment: Thanks, I knew a little about messaging system but your article made things simple

Answer (score 1):

That is a problem with ViewModelLocator (to pass the parameters to ViewModel from View xaml). What you can do is Create a Property Parameter of Type object or (of type your SelectedItem) in ViewModelLocator class. Bind this to the SelectedItem of your Grid and then pass it to your new ViewModel. I hope this will help. **NOte:** If you create the property of type object don't forget to cast it.

Comment: If I understand you correctly your approach can work but it will be very difficult to manage a huge system. Could you please provide some code sample to help me understand. Thanks